# Attach listener to any Firestore collect change

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a document structure of:

```
/uploads/${USER_ID}/items/${UUID}
```

I can successfully listen for changes on the document at the end of the path, for example

```
firestore
    .collection("uploads")
    .document(configService.getUserId())
    .collection("items")
    .whereEqualTo("owner", configService.getUserId())
    .addSnapshotListener(this::onEvent);
}
```

But how can I listen to all changes on `/uploads/*` for changes, without iterating through all documents attaching listeners (Seems very inefficient)?

I naively tried

```
firestore
    .collection("uploads")
    .addSnapshotListener(this::onEvent);
}
```

However, it's not triggered when changes are made down the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). With that you can listen to all documents across all `items` subcollections with:

```
final Query items = db.collectionGroup("items").whereEqualTo("owner", configService.getUserId());
final ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = items.get();
for (DocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot.get().getDocuments()) {
  System.out.println(document.getId());
}
```

---

If you need to know to which upload a specific item belong, you can call [`document.getReference()`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getReference--) to get a reference to the item document, and then follow the [`getParent` trail](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getParent--) from there.

Comment: Thanks for this, `collectionGroup` was the thing I was after. In my use-case I'm able to do what I want with `firestore.collectionGroup("items").addSnapshotListener(this::onEvent);`